# How to save chrome cache for access offline later?

Tags: google-chrome

Some website doesn't online alway. If i access overtime, it redirect to other webpage announce "this service is not available in this period".

But i can access this website in overtime with chrome cache offline (use extension to on/off work offline). And setting in Chrome://flags to enable "show save copy)

Is it possible to save chrome cache to portable for use later.? This cache will be expire?

i try to copy cache folder in  C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data but when i replace for use again sometime it's not work.

When i work offline and click show save copy the webpage blank and chrome said error.

Anyone can suggest me?

Thanks